# Log of heat kernel for positive time

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, heat-equation, geodesics

A well-known [theorem by Varadhan](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160200210/abstract) relates the logarithm of the heat kernel on a manifold and the geodesic distance function.  In particular, if $d(x,y)$ is geodesic distance from $x$ to $y$ and $p(t,x,y)$ is the heat kernel, his theorem shows
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0} -2t\log p(t,x,y)=d(x,y)^2.$$
In other words, you can recover geodesic distance from short-time behavior of the heat kernel.

My question is:  Can we say anything about the function $-2t\log p(t,x,y)$ when $t>0$ is fixed?

For instance:  Can it satisfy the triangle inequality (approximately)?  How does it relate to $d$ or the geometry of the surface?  Is it concave or convex?  Can we say anything about its critical points?

Thanks!

Comment: If your manifold is closed, then the heat equation drives a function towards its average and so $p(t,x,y)\to V^{-1}$ as $t\to\infty$, where $V$ is the volume of the manifold. If you want to say something about $-2t\log p$ for any fixed $t>0$, your statement should remain true in the limit $t\to\infty$ when $p$ becomes independent of $x$ and $y$. Also, if $t$ is fixed and $x$ is very close to $y$, we have $p(x,t,y)>1$ and your "distance" is negative. Can you be more specific about what you would like to have?

Comment: there is a recent paper on the long time behavior of heat kernel, see http://msc.tsinghua.edu.cn/~gxu/Public/large%20time%20behavior.pdf

Comment: @Joonas, I'll admit my question is a bit vague.  Basically, a few algorithms in geometry processing use the heat kernel and justify it via this Varadhan paper.  This of course is a perfectly acceptable argument, but I'm hoping to understand what happens as you deviate from the $t\rightarrow0$ case.

Comment: The article linked by @littlelittlelittle has moved to http://msc.tsinghua.edu.cn/~gxu/public/JDG.pdf. Nevertheless, the reader is warned that it doesn't address the question asked by the OP.